# PyTorch TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'scatter_list'

Tags: python, mpi, pytorch, scatter

all. I have a problem with starting a distributed program while using “mpi” as the backend. The program is as follows:

```
def run(rank, size, hostname):
    print("I am {} of {} in {}".format(rank, size, hostname))
    tensor = torch.zeros(1)
    group=dist.new_group([0,1,2])
    if rank == 0:
        scatter_list=[torch.zeros(1) for _ in range(3)]
        dist.scatter(tensor= tensor, src=0, scatter_list=scatter_list, group=group)
        print("Master has completed Scatter")
    else:
        tensor += 1
        dist.scatter(tensor= tensor, src=0, group=group)
        print("worker has completed scatter")
    print('Rank', rank, 'has data', tensor[0])

def init_process(rank, size, hostname, fn, backend='tcp'):
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=size)
    fn(rank, size,hostname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    world_size = int(os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE'])
    world_rank = int(os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK'])
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    p = Process(target = init_process, 
                     args=(world_rank, world_size, hostname, run, 'mpi'))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

However, when the program starts, it always throws an error like:

```
  File "mpi_test.py", line 17, in run
dist.scatter(tensor= tensor, src=0, group=group)
```

`TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'scatter_list'`

The error is emitted by ranks 1 and 2 which don’t need argument: ‘scatter_list’.
I tried many ways, but failed. Does anybody know why?
Thanks for your reading.

Comment: What is `dist`? How does it know from which rank to scatter?

Comment: did you check rank `0` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is also rank `0` in `group`. As a side note, is there any reason why you access the Open MPI environment (this is **not** portable) instead of using MPI subroutines ?

Comment: according to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html, `scatter_list` is* Required only in the process that is sending the data*, but is **not** marked as optional, so you might have to pass an empty list or `null` after all.

Comment: import torch.distributed as dist  \r               All process call the function scatter and data was sent from rank 0 to the other processes.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, rank 0 is also rank 0. Open MPI is the configured environment in my service provider. I have tried to pass an empty list like: (1) [torch.empty()] (2) None. However, they went wrong: (1) non-empty argument is only required in src process. (2) Required type should be List[torch.Tensor].   Consequently, it makes me confused.